# Bad character in the file

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to load the data from cloud and it failed 3 times.

```
Job ID: job_2ed0ded6ce1d4837873e0ab498b0bc1b
Start Time: 9:10pm, 1 Aug 2012
End Time: 10:55pm, 1 Aug 2012
Destination Table: 567402616005:company.ox_data_summary_ad_hourly
Source URI: gs://daily_log/ox_data_summary_ad_hourly.txt.gz
Delimiter:
Max Bad Records: 30000


Job ID: job_47447ab60d2a40f588c89dfe638aa438
Line:176073205 / Field:1, Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered. Rest of file not processed.
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
```

Should I try again? or is there any issue with the source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug dealing with gzipped files. The only workaround currently is just to use an uncompressed file.

There are changes coming soon that should make it easier to handle large, uncompressed files (imports will be faster, and file size limits will increase).